# Trigger.io: getting an error during package android

Tags: android, trigger.io, forge

It seems like I cannot package for Android anymore. I'm getting the following log output during `forge package android`:

```
[   INFO] Aligning apk
[  DEBUG] Running: '/Applications/android-sdk-macosx/tools/zipalign' '-v' '4' '/var/folders/yj/xppddpjx0k9dwz7z_2bndn5w0000gn/T/tmpEkVeiw' '/path-to-app/release/android/xxx-1404985008.apk'
[  ERROR] Something went wrong that we didn\'t expect:
[  ERROR] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[  DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/build-tools/forge/async.py", line 106, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Applications/TriggerToolkit.app/Contents/MacOS/build-tools/forge/main.py", line 463, in package
    build_to_run=build_to_run,
  File "/path-to-app/.template/generate_dynamic/customer_goals.py", line 147, in package_app
    build_to_run.run()
  File "/path-to-app/.template/generate_dynamic/build.py", line 334, in run
    self._call_with_params(task_method, task_args)
  File "/path-to-app/.template/generate_dynamic/build.py", line 293, in _call_with_params
    return method(self, *params)
  File "/path-to-app/.template/generate_dynamic/android_tasks.py", line 778, in package_android
    _align_apk(path_info, signed_zipf_name, output)
  File "/path-to-app/.template/generate_dynamic/android_tasks.py", line 470, in _align_apk
    run_shell(*args)
  File "/path-to-app/.template/generate_dynamic/module_dynamic/utils.py", line 338, in run_shell
    raise state.error
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm using Trigger.io command line tools on a Mac and also tried it with the Toolkit - same error. Could this have anything to do with updating the Android SDK/Tools to the latest version?

Comment: Just tried it on a system that hasn't installed Android SDK updates in a while and its still working there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed by Trigger.io in their [v2.1.9 platform release](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html#v219).